# prefix operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm overloading the `++` prefix  operator using a member function. Here's the prototype:

```
Test &operator++();
```

But my doubt comes when I use it for my object like below:

```
Test t;
++t;
```

As far I have learned that for **any operator** overloaded by a member function there should be a object of that same class on **left side** of that operator. But when I am calling this `++` prefix overloaded operator, I don't need any object of `Test` class on the left side.

Why?

Comment: I think you just learned it wrong. Your example is fine.

Comment: @Kerrek SB i read it in a book c++ how to program, 5th edition page 576

Comment: They were probably speaking of binary operators only, as for them the left operand needs to be of the class type. But the word **any** is surely misused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far I have learned that for any operator overloaded by a member function there should be a object of that same class on left side of that operator.

That would hold for any **binary** operator. Pre- and post-incrementations, as well as the dereference operator (`*obj`) are unary operators. They have a single argument (either a function parameter or implied "this" parameter, depending on how you overload the operator) and for overloaded operators this only argument must be of a class type.

> But when I am calling this ++ prefix overloaded operator, I don't need any object of Test class on the left side.

Unary operators don't have a "left" and "right" sides (operands), they only have one operand.

---

Remember that in your case:

```
++t;
```

means just:

```
t.operator++();
```

So - in some twisted thinking - `t` is indeed on the left side. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Test& operator++();
```

is always the prefix operator by C++ standard.

In order to override the suffix operator, you need to use another signature:

```
Test& operator++(int);
```

These signature are known by the compiler and it will correctly override the right operator.

Comment: postfix returns by value, not by reference

Answer (score 2):

You just learned incorrectly. How could you have something on the left side of a unary prefix operator?

The same goes for `operator~`, `operator--` and `operator!`. You don't have anything on the left side of them either.

Answer (score 2):

Then you have learnt wrong...

Your example is fine; that is indeed how to declare an overload for the pre-increment operator.

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading provides a syntax that is slightly different to any other member (or non-member) function. Whether you implement the pre-increment as a member function or as a free function, you are implementing *pre-increment*, and the syntax for pre-increment is `++obj`.